# Conversion from Vector<double[]> to double[][]

Tags: java

How can I convert `Vector<double[]>` to `double[][]` in java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert a Vector to an array by `Vector.toArray()`:

```
double[][] array = vector.toArray(new double[0][]);
```

This maybe slightly faster then for loop, because `Vector` can utilize `System.arraycopy()` on its internal array.

Comment: Shouldn't the double array inside .toArray be initialized to the size of the vector instead of 0?

Comment: Yes and no. Just copy the javadoc: `the array into which the elements of the Vector are to be stored, if it is big enough; otherwise, a new array of the same runtime type is allocated for this purpose.`

Comment: Ah, ok :-). But if it will make a new array if you pass it the wrong size, you could just pass it the right-size array first, so only one array is initialized rather than two.

Comment: Well, I see many people do so. So, if many people do so, the compiler should optimize it. I guess. (There are also many people define a `static final xxx[] EMPTY_XXX_ARRAY`, though. Personally I prefer to create it on the fly, cuz Java do create small object very cheap)

Comment: Object creation in Java is dirt cheap, just I'd still go for the solution that doesn't require possibly creating two arrays. I don't think they work in compiler optimizations **just** because a lot of people invoke a function one way (many people write bad code, but it's hard to optimize that away :-p). Regardless, your solution is still completely valid :-)

Answer (score 3):

This will do it:

```
double matrix[][] = new double[vector.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
    matrix[i] = vector.get(i);
}
```

Note that this references the same `double[]` arrays as in your `Vector<double[]>`. So a change in that will be reflected in the new `matrix[][]`. If you don't want that then you'll have to create a new `double[]` for each iteration and copy the values from the old array to the new array.

Answer (score 0):

Muhammed,

WhiteFang is correct... if you're looking for an "out of the box" solution then have a look at Apache's Commons Collections (http://commons.apache.org/collections/)

It's been over a year since I touched Java, but if I recall correctly, "commons" has converters for Vectors... as well as many, many, many other handy bits of kit.

And BTW: If using a Vector is your choice, and you don't have a good reason to NOT use an ArrayList, then use an ArrayList... It's slightly quicker. Except it's NOT threadsafe; whereas all Vectors methods are syncronised. Explanation here: http://skeletoncoder.blogspot.com/2006/09/java-tutorials-arraylist-or-vector.html.

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: I understand you, I want to use ArrayList like you, but comirva MFCC class's method returns Vector<double[]>. Therefore, I have to use it. Thanks your answer